# Formato fecha, dni y nom telefono python

Tags: python

Estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación y estoy haciendo un programa para la gestión de los clientes de un empresa.

- Podríais decirme como puedo poner que la fecha que introduce el cliente sea en formato dia/mes/año.
- Como poner el numero de teléfono con 9 dígitos y  el dni con 8 dígitos más una letra.
- En el menú donde dice listar los clientes habituales, necesito que cuando me diga el nif, yo tenga que decir si es o no cliente habitual. Tengo esas pequeñas dudas.

Os adjunto lo que tengo escrito de código.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

```py
def agregar_usuario():
    global usuarios
    id = int(input("Ingresa el NIF: "))
    nombre = input("Ingresa el nombre y apellido: ")
    direct = input("Ingresa una direccion: ")
    tel = input("Ingresa el número de teléfono: ")
    correo = input("Ingresa su correo electronico personal: ")
    fecha = input("Ingrese la fecha de hoy: ")

    usuarios[id] = nombre, direct, tel, correo, fecha

def delete(id):
    global usuarios
    del(usuarios[id])
    print("Eliminado")

def listar():
    global usuarios
    for user in usuarios:
        print(
        """
                ID: {}
                Nombre: {}
                Direccion: {}
                Correo: {}
                Fecha: {}
        """ .format(user, usuarios[user][0],user, usuarios[user][1],user, usuarios[user][2])
        )

usuarios = {}

while True:
    print("--- Aplicacion gestión de clientes ---")
    print("--- [1] Agregar usuarios ---")
    print("--- [2] Eliminar usuarios ---")
    print("--- [3] Mostrar usuarios ---")
    print("--- [4] Listar todos los clientes ---")
    print("--- [5] Listar clientes habituales ---")
    print("--- [6] Salir ---")

    try:
        option = int(input("\n Selecciona una opcion: "))

        if option == 1:
            agregar_usuario()
        elif option == 2:
            id = int(input("Ingrese el NIF: "))
            delete(id)
        elif option == 3:
            id = int(input("Ingrese el NIF del usuario:"))
            listar(id)
        elif option == 4:
            listar()
        elif option == 5:
            id = int(input("Ingrese el NIF del usuario"))
            

        elif option == 6:
            break
        else:
            print("Marque una opcion correcta en el menu")
    except:
        print("Por favor ingrese datos válidos")
```

Comment: donde esta el dni?

Answer (score 1):

Dado que parece un ejercicio de clase, te comento algunas cosas para que lo puedas hacer tú.

Tienes varias cosas que no creo que sea la mejor manera de hacerlas.

- Donde van los datos de cada usuario podría ser `usuario = {}` y luego los diccionarios con los datos de cada usuario lo puedes guardar en una lista que sería

```
lista_usuarios = []
```

o un diccionario en que la clave sea el dni y el valor el resto de los datos del usuario

```
lista_usuarios ={'dni': usuario}
```

- Normalmente no sería recomendable el uso de variables globales.
- El número de teléfono suele ser un string, aunque puede ser que lo quieras como `int` por alguna razón, pero el `dni` siempre será `str`.
- Para cargar el diccionario sería algo así como

```
usuario = {'nombre': nombre, 'direcion': direcion, 'tel': tel, 'email': email, 'fecha': fecha}
lista_usuarios[dni] = usuario
```

**Referido a las preguntas.**

Para saber si es un  **cliente habitual** tendrás que añadirlo a los datos del cliente, esto es una simple agenda, no tienes datos de uso.

**Para saber si en un input hay un número** padrías usar unas funciones como estas:

```
def es_numero(num):
    try:
        num = int(num)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def dame_numero():
    sw = False
    while not sw:
        numero = input('Dame un número')
        sw = es_numero(numero)

    return numero

print(f'En número es el {dame_numero()}')
```

La función comprueba que **podría** ser un número pero mantiene el formato de `str`

Para no salir del ciclo con un `break` creo la variable `sw = False`.

Continuará pidiendo números hasta que la función `es_numero` devuelva un True

En la función `es_numero` solo se intenta pasar el `string`a `int` envuelto en un `try` para capturar si hay error.

**El dni con 8 dígitos más una letra.**

```
def es_dni(cif):
    #  cif[-1] nos da el último caracter del string
    if 9 != len(cif) or not cif[-1].isalpha():
        return False
    try:
        #  cif[:-1] devuelve todos los caracteres menos el último
        int(cif[:-1])
        return True
    except:
        return False

def dame_dni():
    sw = False
    while not sw:
        dato = input('Dame tu DNI')
        sw = es_dni(dato)

    return dato

print(f'En DNI es el {dame_dni()}')
```

**Con respecto a la fecha** tienes 2 opciones.

**Pones la fecha automáticamente** con las funciones de `datetime`

```
from datetime import date

fecha = date.today()
```

y tendrás la fecha del sistema de donde puedes sacar los datos

```
anio = fecha.year
mes = fecha.month
dia = fecha.day
```

**Introducir la fecha desde teclado** es lo que seguramente pides.

Pues un par de funciones parecidas a las anteriores.

```
def es_fecha(fec):
    if fec[-3] == '/' and fec[-6] == '/':
        anio = fec[6:8]
        mes = fec[3:5]
        dia = fec[0:2]
        try:
            dia = int(dia)
            if dia <= 31:
                mes = int(mes)
                if mes <= 12:
                    anio = int(anio)
                    return True
        except:
            return False

    return False

def dame_fecha():
    sw = False
    while not sw:
        dato = input('Dame la fecha de hoy dd/mm/aa')
        sw = es_fecha(dato)
    return dato

print(f'La fecha es {dame_fecha()}')
```

Buscas las ` / ´ que estén colocadas en su sitio y luego vas comprobando que los otros "pares" de caracteres sean dígitos. Se comprueba a nivel muy básico que el mes no tenga más de 31 días y que los meses no tengan más de 12.

Viendo las funciones una a una esta creo que se entienda.

Comment: puedes utilizar `datetime.now()` para obtener directamente la fecha.